# Inicializar ESC para controlar motor brushless con gpio

Tags: c

Estoy intentando accionar Un motor brushless con los gpio de una orange pi zero usando wiringPi he conseguido hacerlo girar alguna vez pero no funciona siempre el problema está en la Inicialización del controlador ESC 
cuando funciona hace 2 beep espera un segundo aproximadamente otros 2 beep y ya gira el motor pero normalmente se queda haciendo beep continuamente y no gira.
Lo que me gustaría saber es el procedimiento necesario para iniciar el ESC por lo que he leído para iniciarlo hay que mandar un pulso de 2 milisegundos y luego un pulso de 1 milisegundo pero solo funciona aveces

Comment: ¿Y no será un problema hardware? con lo que cuentas es imposible darte una respuesta... habría que analizar las conexiones, la hoja de características del motor y el código fuente con el que configuras el motor y lo usas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución el problema estaba en que solo indicaba al controlador ESC el pulso máximo 2 ms y es necesario indicarle el máximo y el mínimo 1 ms en el caso de este controlador en ese orden puede ser al contrario el otros
Funciona con este codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#define GPIO 12 //gpio 15 orange pi zero

int main()
{

    int speed = 1500; //MINIMO 1000 MAXIMO 2000
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode (GPIO, OUTPUT);

    //INICIO CONTROLADOR ESC
    /*
    Pulsos de 2000us  durante 2.5 segundos

    |--------| pulso de 2000us para indicar el pulso mas alto al controlador ESC
     _______                                     3.3v
    |       |                                  |
    |       |                                  |
    |       |__________________________________| 0 V

    |------------------------------------------| 20000 us periodo del controlador ESC

    2500 ms / 20 ms = 125 pulsos;
    */
    for(int i=0;i<125;i++)
    {
            digitalWrite(GPIO, HIGH);
            usleep(2000);//2ms
            digitalWrite(GPIO, LOW);
            usleep(18000);//18ms
    }
    /*
    Pulsos de 1000us  durante 2.5 segundos

    |----| pulso de 1000us para indicar el pulso mas bajo al controlador ESC
     ____                             3.3v
    |    |                                      |
    |    |                                      |
    |    |______________________________________| 0 V

    |-------------------------------| 20000 us periodo del controlador ESC

    2500 ms / 20 ms = 125 pulsos;
    */

    for(int i=0;i<125;i++)
    {
            digitalWrite(GPIO, HIGH);
            usleep(1000);//1ms
            digitalWrite(GPIO, LOW);
            usleep(19000);//19ms
    }
    //FIN INICIO CONTROLADOR ESC

    //Inicio Giro del motor
    while(1)
    {
            digitalWrite(GPIO, HIGH);
            usleep(speed);//us
            digitalWrite(GPIO, LOW);
            usleep(20000-speed);//us
    }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yo no usaría `usleep` ya que esa función garantiza que el proceso va a estar dormido, como mínimo, el tiempo que le indiques... pero no implica que se vaya a despertar inmediatamente después... es preferible implementar una espera activa

Comment: Que puedo usar entonces ?

Comment: ``void delay(int segundos) 
    {
      for(int i = (time(NULL) + secs); time(NULL) != i; time(NULL));
    }``

algo asi seria mas correcto ?

Comment: si necesitas precisión de milisegundos `time` no te va a servir

Comment: `void msDelay(int microsegundos)
{
   struct timespec tim;
   tim.tv_sec = 0;//SEGUNDOS
   tim.tv_nsec = microsegundos*1000;
   nanosleep(&tim , NULL);
}` creo que esto puede servir

Comment: sin probarlo desde luego tiene mejor pinta

Comment: Lo he probado y el motor mantiene mejor la velocidad antes hacia algún pico con velocidad más alta

Comment: eso es por el uso de `usleep`, dormir un proceso no es compatible con sistemas de tiempo real... como es la gestión de tu motor